# 'The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found' Error connecting mongodb to spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to connect Spring to Mongodb. But it doesn't work somehow. In general, I've used **Spring core 5.0.1, Spring data 2.0.1 ang Mongdodb driver 3.5.0**. I also used the tag **mongo:mongo-client host="localhost" port="27017"** in creating an MongoDb Template bean. The dependencies were fully downloaded but probems still happened.
Please help. Here is the files:

*SpringConfig.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
      xsi:schemaLocation=
      "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client host="localhost" port="27017"/>

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="WebDB" />

</beans>
```

*App.class*

```
package com.erc.myspring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");
        MongoTemplate mongoOperation = (MongoTemplate)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    }

}
```

*pom.xml* (if neccesary)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.erc</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebCom</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebCom Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <mongodb.version>3.5.0</mongodb.version>
        <cxf.version>2.5.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Data mongodb -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Json -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-release</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebCom</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the *error message*:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from class path resource [SpringConfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo-client'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    (+ 7 at something sentences)
    at com.erc.myspring.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo-client'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    (+20 at something sentences)
    ... 9 more
```

The problem may refer to the line *'mongo:mongo-client...'* in SpringConfig.xml, but I haven't found any way to fix that - since 2 days ago. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the schema declaration

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
```

with

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
```

Comment: Wonder why those Spring guys write this non-working example

Comment: Jim, I am glad it works. If you look at my answer, there is an upward pointing triangle above the zero, can you click on it please? I'm a java guy but my creds show that I'm better at .NET, which is so not true.

Comment: I've pressed already but I got 9 reputation points right now.